# How to find app ID for iOS automation using Appium?

Tags: ios, macos, selenium, appium-ios

I want to find the app ID for Appium for Automation. This app is only installed my phone and not available in XCode. Is there a way to find the app path and app ID from phone or mac device?
The reason for asking this very old question is currently I am not able to setup iTunes in Mac OS Big Sur.
A detailed process of identifying the necessary parameters will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can view the apps on the connected iPhone using ideviceinstaller.

If ideviceinstaller is not installed, you can install it with this command.

**brew install ideviceinstaller**

Then you can run this command for single iPhone

**ideviceinstaller -l**

If multiple iPhones are connected

**ideviceinstaller -u device_uuid -l**

you can use these commands

Comment: That helps but when I use "AppID" in Appium and put the ID name to inspect then it still throws error. Do I need to put "AppPath" as well for element inspection? If yes, then how do I get that?

Comment: You can use bundleid to open app-->capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "your_app_bundle_id");                                                                                                                      your_app_bundle_id, It is the app id returned from the ideviceinstaller command.

Comment: You can use it like this in java, I forgot to mention.

Comment: using it in Java is not a problem. I'm trying initiate a inpection session in Appium. Using  the AppID or the BundleID I cannot create the inspect session in Appium. I need the App Path.